# Notification that iTunes has been started

Tags: com, sdk, itunes, notifications

I'm currently developing an application which uses the iTunes COM (Win32) to hook into the iTunes application.

At the moment, I have managed to unhook the COM when iTunes closes through the use of the `OnQuittingEvent` which is great, iTunes doesn't display the application interface dialog so  everything is good.

My problem arises when I re-open iTunes. It seems that it doesn't send the `onCOMCallsEnabledEvent` that I would expect - iTunes is starting, so surely the COM calls would be enabled. So my question is, does anyone know of any notifications that iTunes sends when it's started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so my best bet is just to keep waiting to see if the iTunes process is back again. Solved.

Answer (score 2):

use itunes visual plugins

Comment: I can't believe I didn't look through this! I'll check it now.

Comment: For windows version please see:http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn/tn2098.html
you can download the sdk from apple sdk website, and there is a sample codes in the SDK